# JMeter 2.11 different number of responses from view results tree and jtl file

Tags: jmeter, listeners

I am running *Jmeter* in *non-gui* mode with two `listeners` (aggregate data and view results tree) in test plan. When I load the (aggregate data)`.jtl`  file and (view results tree)`.csv`  file i have different numbers of responses.

For example: 12602 responses from view results tree and 9980 responses from aggregate data.

Can anyone tell why this is happening?

Comment: do you have the same inclusions in both listeners (errors and successes/successes only/etc)?

Comment: Yes, in both listeners I have empty checkbox'es: Errors and Successes (Log/Display Only). In Sample Result Save Configuration I have checked the same checkboxes.

Comment: Do you have an sub-samples, ie assertions, post-processors, debug samples? any of these can create extra results in view tree listener, but not included in aggregate report. Compare the jtl files and see if you can identify any of the extra samples.

Comment: Thank You CharlieS, your advice was very helpful.